# Doesn't work SpEL java.util.Properties . Maven Tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I try to use SpEL with java.util.Properties in my applicationContext.xml. else I use maven tomcat plugin.

my class:

```
public class FieldClass{
 private Properties pr;
 public Properties getProperties(){
  return this.pr;
 }
 public void setProperties(Properties properties){
  this.pr = properties;
 }  
}
```

my xml:

```
<bean id="field" class="com.myproject.app.FieldClass">
        <property name="pr" value="#{systemProperties['APP.LOG_PATH']}" />
    </bean>
```

then i run `mvn -DAPP.LOG_PATH=/Users/wsaryada/tmp tomcat7:redeploy`in command line. but i have compilation fail.

i also tried specify properties in pom.xml in this way:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
          <server>tomcatserver</server>
          <systemProperties>
            <APP.LOG_PATH>/home/user/tmp</APP.LOG_PATH>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

but it doesn't work too.
also i've tried use `<property name="pr" value="#{systemEnvironment['APP.LOG_PATH']}" />`
but here the same problem

> FAIL - Deployed application at context path /application but context
>   failed to start

Where is the problem???

after I commented bean all work successful

**update**

I changed Spring instead Properties in class and deploy error disappeared, but the pr's value became empty

Comment: what is there in tomcat log ?

Comment: "but i have compilation fail", and what is the nature of the failure?

Comment: I doubt that compilation fails, I suspect deployment fails. Tehre is no property named `pr` on your `FieldClass`. You only have a property named `properties`

Comment: doesn't work bean because if i comment it, all working successful

Comment: M. Deinum, yes this error only on stackoverflow i'll edit it in few seconds. it isn't a problem

Comment: Even if it would be `properties` it would fail. YOu cannot convert a single `String` into a `Properties` object. A `Properties` object is basically a `Map<String, String>` which requires a key and value. You are only providing a value...

Comment: if i change String instead properties it doesn't work too. How i can implement it with java.util.Properties?

Comment: it start to work when i use only mvn tomcat7:run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Properties object in Java is essentially a collection of key - value pairs.

In spring, when you inject a property, you reference its key in your xml file, and the value is injected into your code.  Therefore the object type in your java code should reflect whatever the data type of the value is (string, int, etc...).

Also, when you are injecting properties with Spring, there are a few rules:
1) The name of the property in your xml should be the same as the name of the attribute in the java code.
2) Getters and Setters should exist for your java attribute.
3) The names of the Getters and Setters should have the same name as your attribute, but with get or set added to the front, e.g. getPr(), setPr().

Let me know if that helps at all.